# Can I remove non-alphanumeric characters within a Case When in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

Due to the fact that I can't create any function nor procedure, I have trouble solving issues when writing sql queries. This is what my current query looks like

```
SELECT      ProductData.Customer_ID, ProductData.Product_Type
                CASE
                    WHEN ProductData.Product_Title = 'A_Title' THEN 'A_Title' ELSE 'R_Title' END AS R_Title
                CASE
                    WHEN ProductData.Product_Title = 'A_Title' AND ProductData.Product_Category != 'A_Category' THEN **(REMOVE Non-alphanumeric Character)**
                    WHEN ProductData.Product_Category = 'A_Category' THEN 'A_Category' ELSE 'R_Category' END AS R_Category,
FROM        ProductData
```

I'm hoping to be able to use the following code as a result of the first line of the second CASE WHEN in the (REMOVE Non-alphanumeric Character) above, but still haven't figured out a way to make it work.

```
while @@rowcount > 0
        update  ProductData
        set     Product_Category = replace(Product_Category, substring(Product_Category, patindex('%[^a-zA-Z ]%', Product_Category), 1), '')
```

Advises are greatly appreciated.

Comment: No idea what you are asking here. Are you trying to do this just in a select or update the table? And what are you actually trying to do? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas on improving this question.

Comment: I'm trying to remove non-alphanumeric characters as a result of a Case When. I could definitely use a function if I could, but I can't. That's why I'm trying to see if anyone here has experiences doing that.

Comment: You can't use the code you're *hoping to be able to use* in a SELECT CASE. It's unclear what you're trying to do, however.

Comment: So are you trying to do an update or a select? This question is definitely not clear. You could maybe dump the select into a temp table then update the temp table with your loop?

Comment: Just repeating the same vague explanation is NOT making this any clearer. Updating the table or in a select statement? Doing this type of a replacement inline is going to be extremely difficult (if not impossible). If I had to do this I would use an inline table valued function. Why can't you use a function? That is a strange restriction.

Comment: what version of SQL Server and what is the datatype of `Product_Title`?

Answer (score 2):

Taking the great function from Alan Burstein called [PatExclude8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/117890/), which I'm including here

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatExclude8K
(
    @String VARCHAR(8000),
    @Pattern VARCHAR(50)
) 
/*******************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a string (@String) and a pattern (@Pattern) of characters to remove, 
 remove the patterned characters from the string.

Usage:
--===== Basic Syntax Example
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.PatExclude8K(@String,@Pattern);

--===== Remove all but Alpha characters
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^A-Za-z]%');

--===== Remove all but Numeric digits
 SELECT CleanedString
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^0-9]%');

 Programmer Notes:
 1. @Pattern is not case sensitive (the function can be easily modified to make it so)
 2. There is no need to include the "%" before and/or after your pattern since since we 
    are evaluating each character individually

 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 10/27/2014 Initial Development - Alan Burstein

 Rev 01 - 10/29/2014 Mar 2007 - Alan Burstein
        - Redesigned based on the dbo.STRIP_NUM_EE by Eirikur Eiriksson
          (see: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1585850-391-2.aspx)
        - change how the cte tally table is created 
        - put the include/exclude logic in a CASE statement instead of a WHERE clause
        - Added Latin1_General_BIN Colation
        - Add code to use the pattern as a parameter.

 Rev 02 - 11/6/2014
        - Added final performane enhancement (more cudo's to Eirikur Eiriksson)
        - Put 0 = PATINDEX filter logic into the WHERE clause

Rev 03 - 5/16/2015
        - Updated code to deal with special XML characters
*******************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH
E1(N) AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) AS X(N)),
itally(N) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP(CONVERT(INT,LEN(@String),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM E1 T1 CROSS JOIN E1 T2 CROSS JOIN E1 T3 CROSS JOIN E1 T4
) 
SELECT NewString =
((
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,N,1)
  FROM iTally
  WHERE 0 = PATINDEX(@Pattern,SUBSTRING(@String COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N,1))
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'));
GO
```

Here's an adaptation that you could use.

```
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT N FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS X(N)
)
SELECT      ProductData.Customer_ID,
            CASE
                WHEN ProductData.Product_Title = 'A_Title' AND ProductData.Product_Category != 'A_Category' THEN x.NewString
                WHEN ProductData.Product_Category = 'A_Category' THEN 'A_Category' 
                ELSE 'R_Category' END AS R_Category
FROM        ProductData
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NewString =((SELECT SUBSTRING(Product_Category,N,1)
                                  FROM (
                                      SELECT TOP(CONVERT(INT,LEN(Product_Category),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                                      FROM E1 T1, E1 T2, E1 T3, E1 T4) AS iTally(N)
                                WHERE 0 = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z ]%',SUBSTRING(Product_Category COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N,1))
                                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS x;
```

As mentioned by Sean, and probably others, you should clean your data permanently instead of cleaning eat every time you consume it. The previous SELECT statement can be easily converted into an UPDATE.

```
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT N FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS X(N)
)
UPDATE ProductData SET 
    Product_Category = CASE
                WHEN ProductData.Product_Title = 'A_Title' AND ProductData.Product_Category != 'A_Category' THEN x.NewString
                WHEN ProductData.Product_Category = 'A_Category' THEN 'A_Category' 
                ELSE 'R_Category' END 
FROM        ProductData
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NewString =((SELECT SUBSTRING(Product_Category,N,1)
                                  FROM (
                                      SELECT TOP(CONVERT(INT,LEN(Product_Category),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                                      FROM E1 T1, E1 T2, E1 T3, E1 T4) AS iTally(N)
                                WHERE 0 = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z ]%',SUBSTRING(Product_Category COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N,1))
                                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS x;

SELECT * FROM ProductData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your update code is working fine you just need to handle the loop like the following:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 1

while @i is not null
begin
declare @ids table (id int);
delete from @ids
set @i = null
        update  tb
        set val = replace(val, substring(val, patindex('%[^a-zA-Z ]%', val), 1), '')
        OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @ids
        where patindex('%[^a-zA-Z ]%', val) > 0

select  top 1 @i = id
from    @ids
end
```